# How is it "opinion-based" to ask about the fact that all current emulators "suck" when it actually is true?

Tags: discussion, moderation, specific-question, close-reasons

I tried asking this yesterday: [How is it possible that video game console emulators perpetually suck?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16146/how-is-it-possible-that-video-game-console-emulators-perpetually-suck)

Actually, I asked it earlier in the day, but it was mysteriously "memoryholed", as if this had been the "Arqade" or "History" category of Stack Exchange. 404 Not Found. Baffling. That's why I re-posted it. And then it got downvoted into oblivion, which is equally baffling.

Has this category also been taken over by the same toxic people who make it impossible to even *attempt* to ask any question in those aforementioned categories? Why would they otherwise downvote such a question?

Have you actually tried the emulators yourself? If you had, you wouldn't be able to do anything but agree with me. It's impossible. Unless you have never played a real Nintendo 64 and actually think that Mario Kart 64 is supposed to look like it does in the emulators.

So how is it "opinion-based"? I genuinely want to know how this situation can be, so many years after they first started releasing N64 emulators. I remember a friend running Ocarina of Time completely butchered in an emulator on his 450 MHz Pentium II, in 1999. I could never have imagined that this would be the same 21 years later. But it is. This, objectively, means that the emulators suck. It's not an opinion and was not asking for opinions either. I just want to know why it is. How can it be so difficult to emulate them properly? Why do they not even seem to *try*, since none of them even offer the N64's native resolution as a video mode?

It's incredibly insulting when I spend so much time and effort to compose a perfectly written question and then it's just deleted, "closed" and/or downvoted for seemingly no reason. I even mentioned that I couldn't do better myself, so no reasonable person could even take it as an "insult", even if they were the emulation authors.

Comment: Refer to the help center entry on "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" and I think you'll see why you're getting your question downvoted and closed.  https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: The equivalent answer to your question would be something like "But i have really enjoyed Galaga emulation for 20+ years. It looks pretty good to me. So clearly you are wrong!" If you don't find such an answer "satisfying", then you can understand the problems with your question.

Comment: The issue is not that the question itself is opinion-based, but that all answers to the question will be opinion-based, and therefore there will be no way for users to vote for a single 'best' answer.

Comment: and please don't worry about down votes here in meta, votes here (either way) don't count towards your reputation in the main site. In meta down votes commonly (though not necessarily) indicate *disagreement* with the premise of the question. Stack Exchange is open to the internet, so questions need to conform to some basic rules, and those include being *answerable* without resorting to opinions. Stack Exchange takes a little time to get used to, give it some time.

Comment: This is one of the friendlier SE sites for sure, but people react better when a question doesn't assert "X sucks" in the title or use it as the premise of a question.

Comment: I see the 404 and that may be frustrating if you really need access to the text. That may be related to your "re-posting". You shouldn't try to override the system. If something like that happens in SE, 99.9% of the time there's a good reason that a new user may not yet perceive, and fighting or otherwise trying to override it can eventually lead to *further measures*. Instead, see if you can write a different question that can have a fact-based and reasoned answer, not the "do we all agree that X sucks" kind of facts, the other kind. *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*

Answer (score 16):

You can note that there are 116 other questions about emulation in this site and the majority have not been closed. There is an example here that is still open
[What is it with DS emulation being so slow?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15763/what-is-it-with-ds-emulation-being-so-slow)

The problem isn't with what you are asking, it's with the way you are asking it. Focus your question more, give only the details required and try again. The reasons that emulating SNES or N64 hardware with enough accuracy is almost impossible without FPGA based solutions are suitable for this site, and indeed there are people with knowledge about such machines who could share it.